# Checking if a value is in an array of IDS - using a filter?

Tags: templating, array

Is there an easier way to achieve this?
Perhaps using a `|filter` function?

```
{% set variantIds = [] %}
{% for variant in product.variants %}
  {% set variantId = variant.id %}
  {% set variantIds = variantIds|merge([variant.id]) %}
{% endfor %}

{% if wheelSpacer in variantIds %}
  this spacer
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [`|map`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/map.html) filter would work nicely here:

```
{% set variantIds = product.variants|map(variant => variant.id) %}

{% if wheelSpacer in variantIds %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/filter.html) to get only the variant that matches the `wheelSpacer` variable. This will return an array, so you can use [first](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/first.html) to get the first matching variant (since presumably `product.variants` won't contain duplicate variants). This has the added benefit of getting you the matching variant directly, instead of it's ID:

```
{% set variant = product.variants|filter(variant => variant.id == wheelSpacer)|first %}
{% if variant %}
    {# ... #}
{% endif %}
```

As a sidenote, if your `variants` field is an [Entries field](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries-fields.html), you'll want to use `product.variants.all()` instead.